# Is there any way to monitor the size of data transfer In/Out of database

Tags: monitoring, firebird

I am developing a stock management system using Java Swing Framework and Firebird v2.5

My aim is to calculate the amount of data being transferred In/Out of the database for a defined interval.

I've been searching online, found out that in MySQL they have these monitoring variables Like "Bytes_received" or "Bytes_sent"  which can be used to get Session oriented or Global count for bytes being receive & sent respectively.

Is there any better approach to calculate that?

Comment: The monitoring facilities that Firebird has does not include such a feature.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel whoops, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the assistance, After your feedback I'm trying to monitor my data using packet sniffing and trying to analyze the resulting trace. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894820/how-to-calculate-validate-captured-data-size-on-wireshark)