# How to calculate/validate captured data size on Wireshark

Tags: java, monitoring, firebird, wireshark

I want to monitor data size transferred into and out of my database.
I'm using a Java client application & Firebird v2.5 database. Both are deployed locally on one machine.

It turns out that Firebird does not provide any monitoring variable like "Bytes_received" or "Bytes_sent" that are available in MySQL. as discussed in [Is there any way to monitor the size of data transfer In/Out of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847157/is-there-any-way-to-monitor-the-size-of-data-transfer-in-out-of-database?noredirect=1#comment68999172_40847157)

So I set up some tools to capture the local traffic and analyse it.

1. WireShark - to analyse the captured data
2. RawCap - to capture traffic on the loopback address as 'Wincap' was unable to capture local traffic because of OS limitations i.e for Windows - [RawCap download link](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)

I created a test database and a sample table with two columns

> CREATE TABLE test_table ( id bigint default null, test_col varchar(6) default null);

And populated the table with 1000 entries

id with0, 1, 2, 3, . . . 999   & test_col with ABCDEF

Now RawCap is running & using a simple Java Client app to retrieve all rows.

Now 8 bytes for a bigint size and 6+2=8 bytes for varchar(6) equals 16 bytes per row. And 16KB for 1000 rows. That's my estimation only rihgt, but when I open the dump file created by RawCap in wireshark, apply the display filter of 'gdsdb' as I'm only interested in the DB traffic, open the Statistics > Conversations windows. Bytes received from database server to application is almost twice the size then expected. i.e 33KB

Any idea Why I'm receiving almost double then what expected?

[image: Statistics > Conversation Stats]

**Java Client Source Code**

```
public class TestClient {
    static Connection dbConnection = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:firebirdsql://127.0.0.1:3050/C:\\databases2\\TESTDB.FDB";
            String user = "sysdba";
            String password = "masterkey";

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,user, password);
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM test_table");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            int j = 0;
            int i = 0; 
            String s = "";
            while (rs.next()) {
                i++;
                j = rs.getInt("id");
                s = rs.getString("text_col");
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Finished reading %d rows.", i));
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            dbConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to take a guess, I would think Wireshark is also counting the TCP headers, [which at minimum are 20 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). That would be something like 36 bytes each then, which seems fairly close to what your screenshot says. This is just my first thought though, can't say I'm very well versed in this area.

Comment: @kunruh Sorry I didn't catch you, U mean 36Bytes per packet ? if that's the case i'm receiving 36 packets from DB to App which makes 36x36=1296B, 1.2KB,

so 33KB - 1.2KB  almost  32KB still double then what expected. Am I supposed to ignore some other overhead data as well here

Comment: I've voted to close as too broad. This requires a detailed insight in the protocol, for example each row is preceded by a 'fetch response' which takes 12 bytes per row, then depending on the data type, each column may have up to 0-7 bytes of overhead

Comment: A bit update, before i was applying display filter to be 'gdsdb' to limit the trace to show only DBtraffic, even then the filtered trace had 'Accept', 'Response', 'Connect', 'Free Statement', 'Rollback' & 'Detach' packets which are associated with the gdsdb filter. So i changed the display filter to exclude these packet from trace, I'm getting exactly 32k of data from DB which is exactly the double of what I'm expecting i.e 16k. 
I used the follwoing filter
(gdsdb.opcode != 9 &&  gdsdb.opcode != 3  &&  gdsdb.opcode !=1  &&  gdsdb.opcode !=67  &&  gdsdb.opcode !=31  &&  gdsdb.opcode !=21)